# google charts json format for date

Tags: google-visualization

```
{ "cols": [ {"label":"Dat","type":"date"},
            {"label":"TotalCustomers","type":"number"}], 
 "rows": [{"c":[{"v":" Date(2010,11,20)"}, {"v": 2}]},
          {"c":[{"v":" Date(2012,06,01)"}, {"v": 2}]},
          {"c":[{"v":" Date(2012,06,04)"}, {"v": 1}]},
          {"c":[{"v":" Date(2012,06,05)"}, {"v": 1}]},
          {"c":[{"v":" Date(2012,06,06)"}, {"v": 1}]},
          {"c":[{"v":" Date(2012,06,07)"}, {"v": 2}]},
          {"c":[{"v":" Date(2012,06,10)"}, {"v": 2}]},]
```

I am using this format of json and sending it through ajax to datatable but this doesn't seem to work..I have been stuck at it for 2-3 days....It would be great if someone could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is your code it isn't valid json. Change the last characters `},]` to `}]}`. See: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help .. i figured dat out.can u please help regarding how to make a timeframe for my website...ie. i want to provide the option to the user to select data of                                               Last 1 day,Last 7 days...Last month and so on.....but unable to figure out how to implement it ....

Comment: It's impossible to answer to your question. You should make a new question and provide more information about what language you're using, what you have already tried and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found values for v as per e.g.

```
Date(2012, 6, 26)
```

Have worked just fine for me. So...

```
{"v":"Date(2012, 6, 26)","f":"2012-06-26"}
```

Maybe the chart is failing because of your extra space before the word Date?

```
" Date(
```

might help someone